# how to display data in text box in vb.net using sql

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub BtnReturn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnReturn.Click
    If BorrowAccession.Text = "" Or txtBorrowerstype.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("All fields are required.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
    ElseIf txtremarks.Text = "Over Due" Then
        sql = "Select * From `maintenance` fine ='" & txtfine.Text & "' "
        reloadtxt(sql)
 End sub
```

how will i display the fine in txtfine.text from my maintenance database after it satisfy the condition from txtremarks. i tried some youtube tutorials but only displaying it from data grid .. want i basically want is directly display it from database to textbox. btw im newbie in vb programming thank you in advance

for my reloadtxt this is the code.

```
Public Sub reloadtxt(ByVal sql As String)
    Try
        con.Open()
        With cmd
            .Connection = con
            .CommandText = sql
        End With
        dt = New DataTable
        da = New MySqlDataAdapter(sql, con)
        da.Fill(dt)

    Catch ex As Exception
        '   MsgBox(ex.Message & "reloadtxt")
    Finally

        con.Close()
        da.Dispose()

    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Retrieving data from a database and displaying data in a `TextBox` are two unrelated activities. You retrieve data from a database the same way no matter what you intend to do with it and you display data in a `TextBox` the same way no matter where the data came from. I don't see you doing either of those things in that code so maybe you ought to start with one or the other.

Comment: i want to display the data i saved in my table to my text box sir..

Answer (score 1):

To populate an object with data from a database you need to access the objects text property.

```
Textbox1.Text = "Some Text, static or dynamic"
```

Since you are pulling the data from a datatable you would access the column named "fine" and put that value in the textbox.text property.

```
Textbox1.Text = dt.row(0).item("fine").tostring
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed `Or` to `OrElse` because it short circuits the If and doesn't have to check the second condition if the first condition is True.

In the `reloadtxt` method you filled a `DataTable` and did nothing with it. I changed it to a Function that returns the `DataTable`. The connection and command are now included in a `Using...End Using` block so they are closed and disposed even if there is an error.

Never concatenate strings to build an sql statement. Always used parameters.

```
Private Sub BtnReturn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnReturn.Click
    If BorrowAccession.Text = "" OrElse txtBorrowerstype.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("All fields are required.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
    ElseIf txtremarks.Text = "Over Due" Then
        Dim dt = reloadtxt()
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    End If
End Sub

Public Function reloadtxt() As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using con As New MySqlConnection("Your connection string"),
            cmd As New MySqlCommand("Select * From maintenance Where fine = @Fine", con)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(@Fine, MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtfine.Text
        Try
            con.Open()
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message & "reloadtxt")
        End Try
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function
```